# How to calculate Tesla coil secondary inductance with spacing between the wire.

Tags: tesla-coil

I have built a secondary coil for a tesla coil, and I used 24 gauge wire spaced with fishing line the same diameter as the wire.

I have found formulas for no spacing, but not encountered how to figure out inductance with spacing between the wire.

How can I calculate the inductance of the tesla coil if the secondary winding is spaced out instead of being right next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of reference material for calculating inductance. Wheeler's formula  [link here](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/inductance.htm) works well. The length of the coil in the equation takes into account your spacing between turns.

Comment: thanks for the RFCafe link. Their [**Formulae and EE links page**](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical.htm) is amongst the best I've ever seen. RF focus but a large amount of other material. Superb.